# Notation Question: What does $B(0,1)$ mean when it comes to metric spaces?

Tags: metric-spaces

I have to draw the unit balls $B(0,1)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with respect to several metrics, however I am not certain whether this means a unit ball centered at $(0,1)$ or at $(0,0)$? Thanks for your help, hopefully it is an easy question just the book I have uses different notation.

Comment: Center is $0$, radius is $1$, most likely (more properly written $B({\bf 0},1)$).

Comment: I prefer writing the ball, centered at the point $p$ with radius $r$ as $B_r(p)$.

Answer (score 1):

B(0,1) means the unit ball with center in (0,0) and with radius 1.
But the unit ball need not always be a circle! In Euclid (usual) metric space it is a circle, but there are other metrics in which it takes other forms (see unit balls for metric spaces generated by 1 and maximum norms).

Comment: Super thank you

Answer (score 0):

$B(0,1)$ usually means a unit ball centered at the point $\vec 0 = (0,0)$.